# How to fixed 'Unable to render Card preview' twitter error?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter, twitter-card

I am trying to implement twitter share on my site. For this i have added these meta tags:

```
<meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>
<meta property="twitter:site" content="@abc"/>
<meta property="twitter:title" content="dummy text"/>
<meta property="twitter:description" content="dummy text"/>
<meta property="twitter:url" content="http://example.com/example"/>
<meta property="twitter:image:src" content="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/example.jpg"/>
<meta property="twitter:domain" content="The Example"/>
```

When i am trying to check card preview using twitter card validator. i get this error: ERROR: Fetching the page failed because it's denied by robots.txt.

For fix this issue. I have added these line in robot file on server:

```
User-Agent: google
User-Agent: googlebot
User-agent: Twitterbot
Crawl-delay: 10 

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

But i am still getting this issue. Please help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: I think there is a typo error, it will be `User-Agent: Twitterbot` not `User-agent: Twitterbot`.

Comment: I copied these line from : https://dev.twitter.com/cards/getting-started#crawling

Comment: May be I'm not well versed with all this, but there is noting harm with try different options, just replace it with `User-Agent: Twitterbot` and see if you have any luck or not.

Answer (score 0):

I never saw the robots.txt error.

Try adding `<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@abc">`

FWIW I don't use `src` on images.

Try 
`<meta property="twitter:image" content="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/example.jpg"/>`

Comment: Are you sure about not being able to preview unless you're the creator? I feel like I've seen previews from links that I was posting to lots of websites...

Comment: My website has twitter cards before the twitter:creator meta added. Today, it stopped working and i added this meta but nothing changed. It is wordpress yoast seo supported web page

Comment: @AlexMorris You are correct. [Twitter Card Validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) works with any link now.